# Как сравнить два List<T> по свойству?

Tags: c#

Есть два списка List<DB> lst1 и lst2

```
public class DB
{
    public string FilePath { get; set; }
    public List<string> Objects { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public List<string> Keywords { get; set; } = new List<string>();
}
```

Как сделать `Except` между двумя списками по свойству `FilePath`?

Comment: `Как сделать Except между двумя списками по свойству FilePath?` как это понимать? Приведите примеры на входе и выходе.

Comment: @tym32167 VladD бы не спрашивал, суть вопроса очевидна.

Comment: @Athari ну так пишите ответ, раз очевидна

Comment: [#](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs)

Comment: @Athari как это применить к строковым спискам `по свойству FilePath` ?

Comment: Списки с чем у вас? И какое отношение к вопросу имеет приведенный код?

Comment: @Athari, так и обычный Except принимает [`IEqualityComarer`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Except__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEqualityComparer___0__)

Comment: @Grundy Да, но гораздо приятнее использовать однострочник, а не городить целый класс ради одного запроса.

Comment: @Athari, потому что целый класс уже кто-то нагородил? :-)

Comment: @Grundy Давайте, расскажите, как можно написать короче, чем `α.ExceptBy(β,δ=>δ.θ)`, при этом используя только стандартную библиотеку.

Comment: @Athari, через `Enumerable.Except` - это же очевидно.

Comment: Тут мне кажется заголовок не совсем соответствует вопросу. Если нужно при **любом** сравнении DB использовать FilePath, логично просто переопределить Equals и работать со стандартным LINQ. Если нужно однократно сделать Except по FilePath, MoreLINQ действительно позволяет сделать это короче. Только не забывайте про конфликты (не импортируйте все их пространство имен, только нужные методы).

Comment: @Athari, так-то MoreLinq делает использует стандартную библиотеку :-) но я вообще думал про [Comparer<T>.Create](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.comparer-1.create?view=netframework-4.7.20) но похоже он тут не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы попробовал что-то такое

```
var except=lst1.Where(x=>!lst2.Any(y=>y.FilePath==x.FilePath));
```

Comment: O(n^2), лучше поместить все lst2.Select(y=>y.FilePath) в HashSet и искать в ней

Answer (score -1):

Я сделал вот так

```
   public static IEnumerable<DB> ExceptAx(this List<DB> x, List<DB> y)
        {
            foreach (var xi in x)
            {
                bool found = false;
                foreach (var yi in y) { if (xi.FilePath== yi.FilePath) { found = true; } }
                if (!found) { yield return xi; }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Квадратичная сложность же, лучше использовать промежуточную HashSet примерно как в MoreLinq

Comment: @АндрейNOP можно поподробнее?

Comment: Вам в комментарии к вопросу давали ссылку на github: https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/b2c7ad35d13815a5dbc6a5ed26996b99b936ee30/MoreLinq/ExceptBy.cs#L85